# Get Fragment dynamically attached to <FrameLayout>?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-framelayout

Well, i got a simple `<FrameLayout>`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/FragmentContainer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Then in my code, i added a Fragment to it:

```
FragClass aFrag = new FragClass();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.FragmentContainer, aFrag).commit();
```

And somewhere else in my code, i want to get that `FragClass (extends Fragment)` object from the ID `R.id.FragmentContainer`.

i have tried

```
((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer)).getChildAt(0)
```

or

```
((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.FragmentContainer)).getChildAt(0)
```

but they are returning the `View`, instead of the `Fragment` attached to it.

*i know i can keep the variable `aFrag` somewhere, so i do not need to find it again. But i believe there should be a way to retieve it.*

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById%28int%29

Comment: Thanks for reply @Luksprog. But i cannot add an ID to aFrag.

Comment: No even if you use the method above with `R.id.FragmentContainer`?

Comment: Oh yes! Bingo! i've been asking stupid question (Sh...) The answer would be: `((aFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FragmentContainer))`. Thanks @Luksprog

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Let me wrap it up by a full answer :)

In this case, the dynamically added `Fragment` uses the ID of the container `View` (`ViewGroup`).

ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding

> Note: Each fragment requires a unique identifier that the system can use to restore the fragment if the activity is restarted (and which you can use to capture the fragment to perform transactions, such as remove it). There are three ways to provide an ID for a fragment:
>
> - Supply the android:id attribute with a unique ID.
> - Supply the android:tag attribute with a unique string.
> - **If you provide neither of the previous two, the system uses the ID of the container view.**

It is because it's a `Fragment` afterall. We have to use `getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` to retrieve it, which returns a `Fragment`, instead of `findViewById()` which returns a `View`.

So the answer to this problem would be:

```
((aFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FragmentContainer))
```

*Thanks to @Luksprog.*

Comment: It may return null when container activity is launched?

Comment: @HassanMakarov - Thanks for comment. Sorry that I have not been coding Android for a few years. So please take my reply with a grain of salt. As I have attached aFrag to FragmentContainer, why will it return null? Could you please explain more?

Comment: Fragment is not a subclass of View, so a container view can have the same id with a Fragment. Right?