# check which fragment is loaded in framelayout before replacing it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout, fragmenttransaction

Is it possible to check whether a fragment has already been loaded into a FrameLayout before adding it?

Comment: I think I've found what I was looking for [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492717/get-fragment-dynamically-attached-to-framelayout?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

```java
Fragment a = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.FrameLayout);

if(a == null)
    FrameLayout is empty
```